# I'm getting "500 : Command not understood" in Windows server IIS

Tags: iis, http-status-code-500

I'm getting "500 : Command not understood" in IIS when I try to copy and paste a file to a folder in a ftp server, using a particular ftp username. Getting the same error while used filezilla to upload a file to the folder.

We also tried giving read, write, modify rights to that ftp user, no use.

If anybody need any details about the server to get a clear idea, I'll provide.

Comment: Is it FTP over SSL?

Comment: The same here. Any solution out there?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to set UNIX-like permissions on Windows Server IIS.

you really don't need FTP to change permissions. The ACL on Windows is extremely different from UNIX. Windows has so many other access attributes other than read/write/execute. However there is an equivalent of CHMOD command on 2k3 which is called cacls.exe. You can type cacls.exe /? on command prompt to get detailed help or search the web for it.

You also go through the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271071 to know more about IIS specific permission required etc.

happy to help :)